# Stored procedure not updating table

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

Hi still trying to debug this issue so I've stripped things down to the bare basics, following the PHP manual.

SP:

```
DROP IF EXISTS(`login_validator`);
CREATE PROCEDURE `login_validator` (
    IN Username VARCHAR(75),
    OUT ReturnValue VARCHAR(1000)
)
BEGIN
END
```

PHP call:

```
$SP1SQL = 'call login_validator(:Username, :ReturnValue)';
$Stmt = $DBConnection->Prepare($SP1SQL);
$Stmt->BindParam('Username', $Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Return = null;
$Stmt->BindParam(':ReturnValue', $Return, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1000);
$Stmt->Execute();
```

I get:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine myDB.login_validator is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Everything I read says this should work...

I'm trying to get this sp to update the user_login_attempts tbl if the user enters the wrong username and return some values to the calling script.
When called The SP runs without errors and returns only one value

I expect it's some flaw in my logic, but I can't spot it...

I'm calling it like this

```
$SP1 = 'call login_authentication(:Username, :LoginIP, :IPGeoLocation, @ReturnStatus)';
// binding variables
// execute
If I vardump
$SP1RS = $Stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($SP1RS);
```

I get back the correct value of v_Username and all the other values are set to SP's default declarations

If I call it the usual way

$SP1 = 'call login_authentication(:Username, :LoginIP, :IPGeoLocation, :ReturnStatus)';

I get the error MySQL :: Error 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 4 for routine login_authentication is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `login_authentication`(
IN `v_Username` VARCHAR(75),
IN `v_LoginIP` VARBINARY(16),
IN `v_IPGeoLocation` VARCHAR(30),
INOUT `v_ReturnStatus` VARCHAR(1000)
)
BEGIN
 DECLARE v_QueryDB BOOLEAN DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE v_Error BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_ErrorMsg VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE v_Attempts TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_LastAttempt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT null;
DECLARE v_Hash VARBINARY(256) DEFAULT null;
# DECLARE v_LoginIP VARBINARY(16) DEFAULT INET_ATON(v_LoginIP);
SET v_LoginIP = INET_ATON(v_LoginIP);


# Check if user has any previous unsuccessful login attempts
IF EXISTS(SELECT Username FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = v_Username AND Attempts > 4) THEN
SELECT Attempts INTO v_Attempts FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = v_Username;
SELECT LastAttempt INTO v_LastAttempt FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = v_Username;    # Get time of last users last login

# User has been  timed out
IF (v_Attempts = 5 AND v_LastAttempt > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 minute)) THEN
SET v_Error = 1;
SET v_ErrorMsg = 'Sorry, you are still timed out!';
SET v_QueryDB = 0;
END IF;

# other conditions

END IF;

# Query DB for valid username
IF (v_QueryDB = 1) THEN
# Query DB for password hash
IF EXISTS(SELECT Password FROM users WHERE(Email = v_Username || Mobile = v_Username)) THEN
SELECT Password INTO v_Hash FROM users WHERE(Email = v_Username || Mobile = v_Username);
ELSE
# Username not found in DB
# Update user logins table with failed attempt if not already locked
IF (v_Attempts < 7) THEN
INSERT INTO users_login_attempts(
Username,
Attempts,
IPAddress,
IPGeoLocation)
VALUES(
v_Username,
v_Attempts,
v_LoginIP,
v_IPGeoLocation)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Attempts = Attempts +1,
IPAddress = VALUES(IPAddress),
IPGeoLocation = VALUES(IPGeoLocation);

# Update Attempts from DB
SELECT Attempts INTO v_Attempts FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = v_Username;
END IF;
END IF;


# Set error messages for failed login attempts
IF (v_Attempts > 0) THEN
SET v_ErrorMsg = 'The supplied credentials were not recognised'; # Default msg

IF (v_Attempts = 5) THEN
SET v_Error = 1;
SET v_ErrorMsg = 'Due to repeated failed login attempts, Your account has been temporarily locked for 10 minutes!';
END IF;

# more conditions
END IF;
END IF;


# set output result
IF (v_Hash != null) THEN
SELECT v_Hash AS PasswordHash;
    ELSE
    SELECT v_ErrorMsg AS ErrorMsg,
    v_Attempts AS LoginAttempts,
    INET_NTOA(v_LoginIP) AS IPAddress,
    v_Username AS Username;
END IF;


END
```

Answer (score 0):

check this line:

```
$Stmt->BindParam(':Username', $Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

especially ':Username'